# Vowpal Wabbit: make test failing for me at test 59

Tags: vowpalwabbit

For some reason I am having trouble with the `make test` statement while installing ```Vowpal Wabbit``.  I am getting the following error:

```
RunTests: test 59: '/usr/bin/timeout 20 ../vowpalwabbit/vw -d train-sets/argmax_data -k -c --passes 20 --search_rollout oracle --search_alpha 1e-8 --search_task argmax --search 2 --holdout_off' failed (exitcode=1)
```

Anyone have a clue what this could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the command which failed (in single quotes) directly from the `test` directory, and the reason would become obvious.

It is missing data file:

```
Reading datafile = test/train-sets/argmax_data
can't open: test/train-sets/argmax_data, error = No such file or directory
vw: std::exception
```

The issue was introduced in a recent check-in and should soon be fixed (hopefully).

*Update (2014-05-31):* fixed in the most recent commit.

Comment: Would this error be related to the following error I get when running through the tutorial?  ```vw house_dataset -l 10 -c --passes 25 --holdout_off
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::program_options::unknown_option> >'
  what():  unknown option holdout_off
Aborted```

Comment: No.  This is a totally different issue which I can't reproduce.  The error tells me that there's something wrong with your particular build.  Did you see any errors or warning during the build?  An: unrecognised option should give a different error like this: `vw: unrecognised option '--zzzzz'`

Comment: I don't think there were any errors during installation.  I re-installed and still getting the same problem.  When I run ```vw house_datase```t, I get similar output to the tutorial, but at the end I see the following error: ```error: 'second_house is not a float```.  Is it possible that there is a problem running this using Elementary OS Luna?

Comment: I believe there's a bug filed on this: `https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/issues/318` - Essentially the `boost_program_options.so` shared obejct (library) wasn't found during build.  You can fix this by pointing the top level `Makefile` -L ... argument to the place where this library resides on your particular system, and rebuild.  Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Latest `vw` version 7.7 (2014-06-18) has a more robust Mac OS-X build set of rules which should play nicer with homebrew.